# How can I get localization on Route in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I need to make, if path is `'/blog/'` then `locale == en`, but if path is `'/uk/blog/'`, then `locale == uk`.

I'm trying to do it this way:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{locale?}'], function() {
        Route::get('blog', 'App\Http\Controllers\BlogController@index);
        // more routes;
    });
```

But if I try to do '/blog' than `locale == blog` too.

How can I make it so that `locale` is checked for `uk`?

Comment: Did you try `https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add constraints to your route parameters:

```
// Route for /blog without locale
Route::get('blog', 'App\Http\Controllers\BlogController@index');

// Grouped routes for localized paths
Route::group(['prefix' => '{locale}'], function() {
    Route::pattern('locale', 'uk'); // Only "uk" is valid for the locale parameter

    Route::get('blog', 'App\Http\Controllers\BlogController@index');
    // Add more localized routes here...
});
```

Comment: In such cases there is an error. No such route exists.

Comment: @NeverLock It's probably when you hit /blog ? Check updated answer, please.

Comment: Yes. There are more than 50 routs and I don't want to duplicate ones. I need to check locale prefix, and if it uk than 'uk/url...', but if no than '/url...'.

Comment: I tried another way, but chose your way.